# Compactness of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

let $e(j)$ denote the canonical Hilbert base of $l^2(\mathbb{C})$, then define a linear operator by $T(e(j))=\frac{1}{1+j} e(2j)$. I know that this operator is compact. My question occurs within the proof of it:

Define the linear operator of finite rank $T_k(e(j))=T(e(j))$ if $j<k$ and $0$ is $j\ge k$. With this operator one can show that the operator norm $$\|T-T_k\|=\frac{1}{k+1}$$ and hence is zero for $k\to \infty$. This shows the compactness of $T$.

My question: It is already obvious that $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ $(T_k-T)=0$ and hence the norm $$\|\lim_{k\to\infty}T-T_k\|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|T-T_k\|=0.$$
Is this a coincidence that I can interchange limit and norm here?

I assume not, because I can make the $T_k$-construction for any linear operator and hence any operator is compact, which is not the case. But why does it seem to work here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a coincidence. The *definition* of "$\lim (T-T_k)=0$" is "$\lim||T-T_k||=0$".

No, you can't do the same for any operator. You can't show that $||T-T_k||\to0$. (Let $Tx=x$. What is $||T-T_k||$?)

Comment: I should have been more precise: I meant that $lim_{k\to\infty} T_k(x)-T(x)=0$ for every $x$. I think from this it follows that $||T_k-T||\to 0$. This also works for $Tx=x$. Or maybe I have not understood your answer properly...

Comment: @user189292 No, $T_kx\to Tx$ for every $x$ absolutely does not imply $||T-T_k||\to0$. If it did then you'd be right that every operator was compact. But letting, for example, $Tx=x$ _shows_ that $T_kx\to Tx$ does not imply $||T-T_k||\to0$.